# How can I have two services configured in one bundle in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, service, bundle

I have searched in the internet for this one without finding a suitable answer. Some comments or explanations suggest me the possibility of having more than one service in a bundle, but no clue on how to do it.
The app I'm working on works with several third party services, so I want to create a service to cope with each of them, but don't want to have 15 bundles around. 
So what I want is to create one bundle to put all the logic related to this third party services and then register a service for each. 
The problem is that as far as I know, I can only have only one `Configuration.php` in a bundle, and not sure if more than one `MyBundleExtension.php`. 
So, anyone has any idea if this is possible and how or if there is a better way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is in [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services). [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) link treats about two dependent services.

You just have to declare your services:

```
#src/PATH_TO_YOUR_BUNDLE/Resources/config/services.yml
    services:
        service_1:
            # ...
        service_2:
            # ...
        service_n:
            # ...
```

Then create your services classes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I read all that, but it doesn't talks about how to use one configuration file or only one extension file for various services, and I'm not talking about dependent services necessarily. It's my app using the diferent services, but it's not heavily dependent on each of them.

Comment: OK, I figured it out, I can use an entry in my app/config/cofig.yml an put all the necessary configuration under it for the services contained in the bundle. This way I don't really need more than one configuration file. Thanks anyway @mansoulx for pointing in the right direction. You made me rethink what I was trying to do, so I'll mark it as answered.